# Can I add Latest-1 build to the Artifacts in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like to build a VSO release workflow that uses the both Latest and Latest-1 builds to check backward compatibility. Can I add Latest-1 build to the Artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify two build artifacts in your release definition to get the latest build artifacts and latest-1 build artifacts. Detail settings as below:

#### 1. Add latest build artifacts for your release definition

In your release definition, add the build artifacts by specifying latest version:

[image]

#### 2. Add latest-1 build artifacts for your release definition

Add another artifacts for your release definition by specifying the default version as Specify at the time of release creation.

[image]

**Note:** you need to specify the latest-1 version manually when creating a new release.

[image]